# How come the preferences activity is launched when selecting my app from the menu displayed when pressing the Home button?

Tags: android

Steps:

1. I start my Android app.
2. I press the Menu button and select Preferences => preferences screen appears.
3. I make a preference and then press the Back button => the application's main activity appears again.
4. I press the Back buttton => Home screen.
5. I press the Home button and select my app => Preferences screen appears...why??

Main activity

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
   startService();
   super.onResume();
}

private void startService() 
{
   ...
   preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);   
   startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WeatherService.class));
   ...
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
   unbindService();
   super.onPause();
}


private void onPreferences() 
{
   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Preferences.class);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

Preference activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

Cheers,
Christian

Comment: Are you using an ActivityGroup ? can you show some code from the two Activities of your application ? (especially OnPause / OnCreate / other such lifecycle handlers)

Comment: Not using ActivityGroup. Added some code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have used "singleInstance" as activity launch mode. If so, try to set it as "SingleTask".